# Intellij idea using 10001 port

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA 12 Public Preview by default is listening to 10001 port for one of its plugins. In our company we use this port for other purposes and there seems to be no easy way to change this... Can anyone suggest any options? Been googling for about an hour to no avail.

Comment: What plugin? Can you disable it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA EAP builds come with the **YourKit Java Profiler** agent enabled by default so that users can take CPU and Memory snapshots out of the box to report performance problems.

The agent is enabled via `idea(64.exe).vmoptions` file:

```
-agentlib:yjpagent=disablej2ee,disablealloc,sessionname=IntelliJIdea12
```

You can remove this line to disable profiler agent that will free up 10001+ ports.
Another solution is to change the default port using [agent options](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/11/help/startup_options.jsp):

`-agentlib:yjpagent=disablej2ee,disablealloc,sessionname=IntelliJIdea12`**,port=31337**

If you are on Mac, this configuration is done via `Info.plist`, see the [FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-197).

On Linux it's added in `idea.sh` script:

```
IS_EAP="true"
if [ "$IS_EAP" = "true" ]; then
  OS_NAME=`echo $OS_TYPE | "$TR" '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
  AGENT_LIB="yjpagent-$OS_NAME$BITS"
  if [ -r "$IDE_BIN_HOME/lib$AGENT_LIB.so" ]; then
    AGENT="-agentlib:$AGENT_LIB=disablej2ee,disablealloc,sessionname=IntelliJIdea12"
  fi
fi
```

Just change to `IS_EAP="false"` or delete the agent `.so` file to disable it.

Following Vladimir's suggestion I've [created a request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94892) to use **onlylocal** option by default, feel free to vote.

Comment: I have two files in my idea installation directory / bon folder: idea.vmoptions and idea64.vmoptions. Neither of these contrains the line you mentioned. Furthermore, if I manually add such a line Idea just won't start. Both files contain the same: -Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=430m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-ea
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Comment: UPDATE: removing "libyjpagent-linux.so" file located in the same folder did the trick and 10001 port is now free.

Comment: I can't get to work on OSX. My Info.plist does not have the yjpagent line. When I add it, I IntelliJ fails to start with an error "SOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error". Has anyone got to work on OSX recently? Can you say in detail what you did?

Comment: @aaa90210 please refer to https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/29983118 for the up to date instructions.

Comment: @CrazyCoder based on those instructions, I would assume that Android Studio does not include yjpagent as it is not open source, but AS is free. Anyway, I did give it a try, but got the "SOpenURLsWithRole()" error again.

Answer (score 5):

As a YourKit developer, I'd like follow-up Serge's answer and recommend to add "onlylocal" to the list of YourKit agent options. This option forces profiler to open port on loopback network interface. Potentially it's more secure and on Windows you will not see security warning.