# Crashlytics plugin not appear Intellij IDEA 14 ( NullPointerException: update failed for AnAction with ID=Actions.Crashlytics.CrashlyticsAction)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, crashlytics

Trying to add plugin into Intellij IDEA 14 but it's not appeared in tools panel(Plugin was downloaded from Crashlytics-site today). I tried to add hot-key for this then in logs got:

```
NullPointerException: update failed for AnAction with ID=Actions.Crashlytics.CrashlyticsAction
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in IntelliJ IDEA EAP builds come with the YourKit Java Profiler. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13347217/1823992) answer helped me to return back crashlytics plugin to work.

Comment: can you explain exactly what you did? I cant find where YJP is enabled so I can disable it. This has been bugging me for ages. Thanks!

Comment: @aaa90210 Follow the link in the answer please. There are described how to edit it according every operation system.

Comment: yes I did - but in my Info.plist there was nothing about yjpagent at all...nothing to disable...yet the problem still occurs. Is there another location I should be looking?

Comment: Are you sure you have  IntelliJ IDEA EAP  build? I recommend to open issue here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=project%3A+%7BIntelliJ+IDEA%7D

Comment: No I am using Android Studio (based on IDEA). I have tried with 1.1 and 1.2RC but get the error with both.

Comment: This may variate. I never came across this problem in AS. You can submit to their bug-tracker https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Comment: Answer given in the link works. you have to edit studio.sh for Android studio.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't solve this issue, I found a way that worked (Android Studio 1.1 on OSX).

Uninstall AS.

Delete the following (~ is home directory of user who runs AS):
~/.android*
~/.Android*
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android*
~/Library/Caches/Android*
~/Library/Android*
~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics*
~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio*
~/Library//Saved Application State/com.google.android.studio.savedState

Then re-install Android Studio and the Fabric plugin, and it should work now.

I don't know if all the above deletes are necessary, but I could not narrow it down any further, and deleting all the above after uninstalling, then re-installing, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Report a bug, let developers to fix it.

Comment: Wanted but didn't found where to report bugs to them.

Comment: please, send it to support@fabric.io

Answer (score 0):

I didn't clear the cache or removed the Android Studio, I've reinstalled Crashlytics plugin again (`File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Install plugin from disk...`) and the issue disappeared.