# When using the node driver, notarisation in flows hangs with a handshake failure

Tags: intellij-idea, corda, yourkit

Whenever I try and test using the node driver, I find at the point of notarisation, my flows will hang.

After examining the node logs, it shows that the notary's message broker was unreachable:

> [INFO ] 09:33:26,653 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] (AMQPClient.kt:91)
>   netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect {}
>
> [INFO ] 09:33:26,657 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-4] (AMQPClient.kt:76)
>   netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Connected to localhost:10001 {}
>
> [INFO ] 09:33:26,658 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-4]
>   (AMQPChannelHandler.kt:49) O=Notary Service, L=Zurich,
>   C=CH.channelActive - New client connection db926eb8 from
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:10001 to /127.0.0.1:63781 {}
>
> [INFO ] 09:33:26,658
>   [nioEventLoopGroup-3-4] (AMQPClient.kt:86)
>   netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Disconnected from localhost:10001
>   {}
>
> [ERROR] 09:33:26,658 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-4]
>   (AMQPChannelHandler.kt:98) O=Notary Service, L=Zurich,
>   C=CH.userEventTriggered - Handshake failure
>   SslHandshakeCompletionEvent(java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)
>   {}
>
> [INFO ] 09:33:26,659 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-4]
>   (AMQPChannelHandler.kt:74) O=Notary Service, L=Zurich,
>   C=CH.channelInactive - Closed client connection db926eb8 from
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:10001 to /127.0.0.1:63781 {}
>
> [INFO ] 09:33:26,659
>   [nioEventLoopGroup-3-4] (AMQPBridgeManager.kt:115)
>   peers.DLF1ZmHt1DXc9HbxzDNm6VHduUABBbNsp7Mh4DhoBs6ifd ->
>   localhost:10001:O=Notary Service, L=Zurich, C=CH.onSocketConnected -
>   Bridge Disconnected {}

While the notary logs display the following:

> [INFO ] 13:24:21,735 [main] (ActiveMQServerImpl.java:540)
>   core.server.internalStart - AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message
>   Broker version 2.2.0 [localhost,
>   nodeID=7b3df3b8-98aa-11e8-83bd-ead493c8221e]  {}
>
> [DEBUG] 13:24:21,735 [main] (ArtemisRpcBroker.kt:51)
>   rpc.ArtemisRpcBroker.start - Artemis RPC broker is started. {}
>
> [INFO ] 13:24:21,737 [main] (ArtemisMessagingClient.kt:28)
>   internal.ArtemisMessagingClient.start - Connecting to message broker:
>   localhost:10001 {}
>
> [ERROR] 13:24:22,298 [main] (NettyConnector.java:713)
>   core.client.createConnection - AMQ214016: Failed to create netty
>   connection {} java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
>       at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(...)(Unknown Source) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
>
> [DEBUG] 13:24:22,362 [main] (PersistentIdentityService.kt:137)
>   identity.PersistentIdentityService.verifyAndRegisterIdentity -
>   Registering identity O=Notary Service, L=Zurich, C=CH {}
>
> [WARN ] 13:24:22,363 [main] (AppendOnlyPersistentMap.kt:79)
>   utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMapBase.set - Double insert in
>   net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMap for entity class
>   class
>   net.corda.node.services.identity.PersistentIdentityService$PersistentIdentity
>   key 69ACAA32A0C7934D9454CB53EEA6CA6CCD8E4090B30C560A5A36EA10F3DC13E8,
>   not inserting the second time {}
>
> [ERROR] 13:24:22,368 [main] (NodeStartup.kt:125) internal.Node.run -
>   Exception during node startup {}
>   org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException:
>   AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available
>   servers.
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:787)
>   ~[artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>       at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.ArtemisMessagingClient.start(ArtemisMessagingClient.kt:39)
>   ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.bridging.AMQPBridgeManager.start(AMQPBridgeManager.kt:195)
>   ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.bridging.BridgeControlListener.start(BridgeControlListener.kt:35)
>   ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.node.internal.Node.startMessagingService(Node.kt:301) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ Ultimate ships with the Yourkit profiler, which by default starts when IntelliJ starts and listens on port 100001 - the default port for the Notary in Driver.

You can locate the config for this using [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235) and alter it to use a different port as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345986/intellij-idea-using-10001-port)

Your new config line will look something like this:

```
-agentlib:yjpagent=delay=10000,probe_disable=*,port=30000
```